# MYSQL Select with IF in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a list of items in MySQL table each one has a group number & unique item number.

I'm Trying to select records that mach 2 criterias.

First I need to select record that satisfies group & item numbers. If none found i want records selected that just belongs to a group.

Only one record has to be selected either way.

Comment: It's not clear what you're looking for. Please post some sample data, the desired output, and your attempted query.

Comment: In general, you don't use `IF` in `WHERE` clauses, you use logical operators `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: does the value of Group you check in second part is same as the value you will use in first check with item id ? for example "give me the records where (groupid=1 and itemid=123)" if no record found then "give me record (where groupid=1)" if so then you could just do straight second check. unless you have some kind of indication in result-set that indicates what conditions qualified with that record, first or second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE GroupID = :group
ORDER BY ItemID = :item DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`LIMIT 1` makes it return just one record. The `ORDER BY` clause makes it prefer a record that matches the item criteria if there is one.

Comment: In fact I just realized that it will not work in my situation. Let me explain what i have here. I need to select a list of discounts for my customer that will have product group, group item number and discount. Say product group has 20% discount but item in this group has 25% discount i need only to select that item. if item number is not specified select a group. So on the output it will be a list of groups & items but not more than 1 in each group.

Comment: Might be best if you started a new question. Please post sample data, desired results, and your attempted solution (if you omit the last, it will probably be put on hold -- requests for code must start with your attempt and why it doesn't work).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

this won't work

```
Select * From MyTable 
Where (GroupID = 1 and ItemID = 2) or (GroupID = 1)
```

this works

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 AND ItemID = 2) 
   BEGIN 
       SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 AND ItemID = 2 
   END 
ELSE 
   BEGIN 
      SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 
   END
```

- replace MyTable with the name of your table
- replace GroupID and ItemID with the name of your columns
- replace number 1 and 2 with whichever value associate with columns you wish to filter

Comment: That WHERE clause is equivalent to `WHERE GroupID = 1`. There's no need to mention `ItemID`.

Comment: I forgot to limit it to 1 record.

Comment: It's simple logic. `x OR y` is true if either `x` or `y` is true. So when `GroupID = 1` is true, the whole expression will be true whether or not `ItemID = 2` is true.

Comment: right so if GroupID = 1, regardless of whatever ItemID it will return the record. The ItemID is to be evaluated along with the group if they both exist

Comment: now that i thought of this... I don't even know if if the "pair" match not found, he wants to return a different group from what was originally in the "pair". (pair as in "GroupID X and ItemID Y" are true). if pair match fails then go find GroupID Z instead of GroupID X.

Comment: oh i just tested it out. it doesn't check the condition in hiarchy. I get it now. It won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Right. If you want to specify order, you have to use ORDER BY. It doesn't use specificity of the WHERE clause as a criteria.

Comment: I'm trying to test with your code/answer but it doesn't work. Maybe I did something wrong. :group is to be replaced with the column value for filtering right?

Comment: Anyway, I came up with this and it works but it looks a little ugly IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 AND ItemID = 2)
BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 AND ItemID = 2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable WHERE GroupID = 1 END

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `SELECT TOP 1`

Comment: I used PDO-style placeholders to represent where his parameters should be substituted. So :group and :item are the GroupID and ItemID he wants to search for.

Comment: Your code probably works fine then. Sorry I wasn't paying attention to the MySQL part. I don't use MySQL. Thanks for being patient with me.

Comment: As Barmar points out, MySQL doesn't have Select Top 1. My bad, I didn't know you were using MySQL. Sorry.